# C# Modify object created in one function from another

Tags: c#, forms

I am attempting to create a list during run time of my program, I have created the list within the createList() function and called the function; however I cannot access the list from the button1_Click() function called after.
How do I access the created list from a different function to the one it was created in.

Code extracts:

```
 public void createlist()
        {

            ListView MainList = new ListView();

            DisplayPanel.Controls.Add(MainList);

            MainList.View = View.Details;
            MainList.GridLines = true;

            MainList.Name = "MainList";
            MainList.Size = DisplayPanel.Size;
            int s1 = DisplayPanel.Size.Height;
            int s2 = DisplayPanel.Size.Width;
            MainList.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top);

            MainList.Columns.Add("ProductName", 100);
            MainList.Columns.Add("ProductName2", 100);
            MainList.Columns.Add("ProductName3", 100);
            MainList.Columns.Add("ProductName4", 100);

        }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            createlist();   //Calls function and creates the ListView

            ListViewItem Source = new ListViewItem("Source", 0);
            Source.Checked = true;
            Source.SubItems.Add("7");
            Source.SubItems.Add("8");
            Source.SubItems.Add("9");

            MainList.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] {Source});

        }
```

Error :
Error   CS0103  The name 'MainList' does not exist in the current context

Comment: You have a compilation error because `MainList` is only valid in `createlist` (BTW: Compilation errors are the ones which are easy to fix. Just read some c# docs )

Comment: Either find it in the `DisplayPanel.Controls` or make it a class-level field.

Comment: The concept you need to learn is called [Scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx).

Comment: scope `MainList` to your class or use `DisplayPanel.Controls` to get a reference to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make this a member of the class in order to access it from a different function.  See below:

```
class Foo{
    ListView MainList = new ListView();
    public void createlist()
        {

            MainList = new ListView();

            DisplayPanel.Controls.Add(MainList);

            MainList.View = View.Details;
            MainList.GridLines = true;

            MainList.Name = "MainList";
            MainList.Size = DisplayPanel.Size;
            int s1 = DisplayPanel.Size.Height;
            int s2 = DisplayPanel.Size.Width;
            MainList.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top);

            MainList.Columns.Add("ProductName", 100);
            MainList.Columns.Add("ProductName2", 100);
            MainList.Columns.Add("ProductName3", 100);
            MainList.Columns.Add("ProductName4", 100);

        }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            createlist();   //Calls function and creates the ListView

            ListViewItem Source = new ListViewItem("Source", 0);
            Source.Checked = true;
            Source.SubItems.Add("7");
            Source.SubItems.Add("8");
            Source.SubItems.Add("9");

            MainList.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] {Source});

        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I made the modification you suggested and put ListView MainList; into the main class with all the functions and the program runs but an error occurs when the button is clicked:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in RCPYC Membership Program.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Edited my answer.  My guess is it flaked out since MainList is not initially set to anything.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because `MainList` is not in the *scope* of the `button1_Click` method.

There are two ways to solve this.

1. Put your `MainList` variable outside of all the methods. This way, the `MainList` variable is in the scope of the whole class which means every method in the class can access it.

   ```
   ListView MainList;
   public void createlist()
   {
       MainList = new ListView();
       DisplayPanel.Controls.Add(MainList);

       MainList.View = View.Details;
       MainList.GridLines = true;

       MainList.Name = "MainList";
       MainList.Size = DisplayPanel.Size;
       int s1 = DisplayPanel.Size.Height;
       int s2 = DisplayPanel.Size.Width;
       MainList.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top);

       MainList.Columns.Add("ProductName", 100);
       MainList.Columns.Add("ProductName2", 100);
       MainList.Columns.Add("ProductName3", 100);
       MainList.Columns.Add("ProductName4", 100);

   }

   // your other method should be here...
   ```
2. Return a value from `createList`.

   ```
   public ListView createlist()
   {
       MainList = new ListView();
       DisplayPanel.Controls.Add(MainList);

       MainList.View = View.Details;
       MainList.GridLines = true;

       MainList.Name = "MainList";
       MainList.Size = DisplayPanel.Size;
       int s1 = DisplayPanel.Size.Height;
       int s2 = DisplayPanel.Size.Width;
       MainList.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top);

       MainList.Columns.Add("ProductName", 100);
       MainList.Columns.Add("ProductName2", 100);
       MainList.Columns.Add("ProductName3", 100);
       MainList.Columns.Add("ProductName4", 100);
       return MainList;
   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

           var listView = createlist();   //Calls function and creates the ListView

           ListViewItem Source = new ListViewItem("Source", 0);
           Source.Checked = true;
           Source.SubItems.Add("7");
           Source.SubItems.Add("8");
           Source.SubItems.Add("9");

           listView.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] {Source});

       }
   ```

I recommend the first solution because it allows all your methods in the class to access `MainList` which you probably want. If you're absolutely sure you don't want to access `MainList` in any other method, use the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

MainList, in your createList() function, is just a local variable to that function and can only used within that function.  In order to be able to access it in other functions, you'll need to make it a class variable.

Comment: That's _one_ way to solve it - you could also find it in the `DisplayPanel.Controls` collection.

Comment: Thanks, how would I go about changing it to a class variable?

Comment: @WillAnderson, In order for you to learn, some research will serve you well rather than me telling you how to do it.  Or look at phishfordead's answer.  Also, are you trying to build a user interface, using Visual Studio, by writing the code out for it?  If so, you may want to consider using Visual Studio's form building designer.

Comment: @Shar1er80 I am using the form designer I just didn't post the whole code as I felt it would make the question unnecessarily long. Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: @WillAnderson, since you're using the form designer is the ListView already on the form?  If so, it already has a variable name assigned to it by which you can access in any function in the class.

Comment: @Shar1er80 No I was creating the ListView in runtime, thank you for the help I have been able to fix the problem and (hopefully) learn how to make this work in future :)